# Chef - Embedding template block inside a conditional check

Tags: ruby, syntax, nested, chef-infra

i'm looking for a bit of ruby help. I've got this code block to check if a my NGIX server is listening on a particular port and if not, then use a Chef template to make the changes and restart the server. The issue i have here is i cant get the syntax right to use the template block inside another Ruby block.

Could i ask for a little syntax help please?

Thanks :)

```
ruby_block "check sayc" do
  block do
    server = node['fqdn']
    port = puts global_ssl_port.to_i

    begin
      Timeout.timeout(5) do
        Socket.tcp(server, port){}
      end
      Chef::Log.info 'connections open'
      rescue
      Chef::Log.fatal 'connections refused'

            #Configures Server NGIX Port
            template '/etc/opscode/server.rb' do
              source 'server.erb'
              mode '0755'
              owner 'root'
              group 'root'
              #Add new NGIX port configuration
              variables(non_ssl_port: global_non_ssl_port, ssl_port: global_ssl_port)
            end

    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still on that in your ruby block you can replace `template` DSL with new instance of `Chef::Resource::Template.new('nginx config')` and set class attributes after that- `source`, `mode` and etc.

Here is the minimum code in order to get `Chef::Resource::Template` running

```
ruby_block 'create template' do
  block do

    r = Chef::Resource::Template.new('template_name', run_context)
    r.path       '/tmp/file.txt'
    r.source     'file.erb'
    r.cookbook   'cookbook_name'
    r.mode       00600
    r.run_action :create
  end
end
```

You need to have `file.erb` in `templates/default/file.erb` for example and you need to replace `cookbook_name` with your cookbook.

Comment: hi GLG, really appreciate the reply. Do you mind updating the answer with an example of the code? i just tried it and couldn't get it to work. thanks again hey.

Comment: I will check it later today

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really how Chef works. You put what you want the config file to look like in the template and if the config is out of date, Chef will update it.

More directly to the question: you cannot use Chef recipe DSL inside a `ruby_block` resource. As the name implies, it allows only plain Ruby code. You would have to make this into a custom resource if you wanted to do something like that. But, again, probably don't :)